# Flutter rebuild dialog element with provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using provider and I want to reconstruct a message contained in a dialog. It seems that dialog is a problem.

When I sprint the values ​​I observe that they are modified but this is not applied in the dialog

In my **screen page** under the build method I have this :

```
var _loaderProvider = Provider.of<LoaderNotifier>(context, listen:false);
```

My button who call the dialog in my **screen page** :

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _formProvider.submitForm(context);
  print(_formProvider.state);
  print(_loaderProvider.state);
  if(_formProvider.state == FormProviderState.isSuccess){

    void myShowDialog() async{
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: _loaderProvider,
              child: DialogComponent.loadingPopUp(description: _loaderProvider.message));
        },
      );
    }

    myShowDialog();


    // Here I change the state of the dialog
    _loaderProvider.state = LoaderState.isLoadingJsons;
    print(_loaderProvider.state);
    await TimerService.wait(2);

    // Here I change the message dialog
    await _loaderProvider.updateMessage();

    print(_loaderProvider.state);
    print(_loaderProvider.message);

  }
},
```

In the print I see that all the variables are updated after 2 seconds but I don't see the modification in the dialog.

**TImerService :**

```
class TimerService{

  static Future wait(int seconds) async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds));
  }

}
```

**The loaderNotifier :**

```
class LoaderNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  LoaderState state = LoaderState.isReady;
  String _message = "Start...";

  String get message => _message;

  Future updateMessage() async {
    print('update message');
    if(state == LoaderState.isLoadingJsons){
        _message = "Loading files...";
    }
    else if(state == LoaderState.isLoadingElements){
      _message = "Loading...";
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

---

**Edit** : I found, I changed my showDialog function :

```
void myShowDialog(){
   final myModel = Provider.of<LoaderNotifier>(context, listen: false);
   showDialog(
     context: context,
     barrierDismissible: false,
     builder: (_) {
       return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
           value: myModel,
           child: Consumer<LoaderNotifier>(
            builder: (context, model, child) => DialogComponent.loadingPopUp(description: model.message)
           )
       );
     },
   );
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you need to notifyListeners and thus listen the changes in the provider. Consumer widget will listen them and update the UI accordingly.

Comment: I'm new to provider but it seemed weird to me because in the documentation it seemed to me that it said to use consumer or then provider.of. Here I have to use the 2.

Comment: But when you use Provider.of with "listen: false" it disables the listeners so that that won't be listening your changes.

Comment: If i remove "listen:false" in my Provide.of and I remove the consumer Widget around my DialogComponent it's not work ... Have you an exemple with my code for have a cleaner way to do ?